# java xmlrpc to confluence

Tags: java, xml-rpc, confluence

I want to upload pages via xmlrpc to confluence.

I can login, but I do not know how to represent a "Page" in java. when calling remote procedure

```
    XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
    config.setServerURL(new URL("xxxxxxx/rpc/xmlrpc"));
    XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
    client.setConfig(config);

    try {
        String token = (String) client.execute("confluence2.login", new String[] {"login","password"});
        //Object page = null;
        //Object result = client.execute("storePage", new String[] {token, (String) page});
        System.out.println(token);
    } catch (XmlRpcException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**What is the type of a page ?**

Answer (score 0):

Easy: according to https://drupal.org/node/1267522 it's just a HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Map. You can see the valid keys/values for the Page map here: https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-xml-rpc-and-soap-apis/remote-confluence-data-objects - look under the "Page"section.